# Visual Studio warning: Undeclared mixin in .less file

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, less

I am using VS 2017. I have bought a CSS template, which is structured as below (I believe it is quite typical):

All the mixins are declared in a file called mixins.less

**mixins.less**

```
.transition-delay(@delay: 0) {
  -moz-transition-delay: @delay;
  -webkit-transition-delay: @delay;
  -o-transition-delay: @delay;
  transition-delay: @delay;
}
// more mixins
```

and then I have several style files which use these mixins (e.g. header.less & product.less)

**header.less**

```
h2 {
  .transition-delay(1s);
}
// more css
```

**product.less**

```
div.someClass {
  .transition-delay(1s);
}
// more css
```

Finally I have style.less, where everything comes together:

**style.less**

```
@import "mixins.less";
@import "header.less";
@import "product.less";
```

when I compile style.less, everything gets complied into style.css and style.css is added to my web project.

This works fine, the only problem is when compiling the project, Visual Studio gives a lot of warnings:

> Undeclared mixin

This is because I am using `.transition-delay` in header.less. VS warning is valid, as I have not declared the mixin in header.less... but then I don't need to compile header.less, the only file that I need to compile is style.less.

Is there anyway to tell VS to ignore header.less and product.less and not give me any mixin warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [Web Compiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.WebCompiler), you can right click the .less file and remove it from compilation:

[image]